# Arrow should only appear in cases expressions and anonymous functions

Tags: dictionary, pattern-matching, elm

I am trying to check if a given key exist in a `dict` given the key. I am relatively new to `Elm` and functional programming, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

The error I am receiving is:

> An arrow should only appear in cases expressions and anonymous functions. Maybe
>   you want > or >= instead?

Here's my attempt at returning `true` or `false`

```
dictExist : comparable -> Dict comparable v -> Bool
dictExist dict key =
    Dict.get key dict        
            Just -> True 
            Maybe.Maybe -> False
```

On another note I have tried the `Dict.member` as well, but no success either and would assume instead of the `Dict.get` I should be using `Dict.member` for this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four problems with your code:

1. As the error points out, you're using the arrow outside a `case ... of` expression.
2. The `Maybe` type's `Just` constructor has an accompanying value, the item from the dict, but you don't bind it to anything. You have to explicitly discard it by assigning it to the wildcard pattern, `_`.
3. `Maybe.Maybe` is not a constructor. This should be `Nothing`, which is the other constructor of the `Maybe` type.
4. You've flipped the argument order of `dictExist`

Having fixed these problems, this code should work:

```
dictExist : comparable -> Dict comparable v -> Bool
dictExist key dict =
    case Dict.get key dict of        
        Just _ -> True 
        Nothing -> False
```

But this is really just a reimplmentation of `Dict.member`, which has [the exact same type signature](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Dict#member). Replacing any usage of `dictExist` with `Dict.member` should therefore work exactly the same.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I did try something similar with the case earlier, but was getting this error `This key value is a:

    Dict comparable v

But get needs the 1st argument to be:

    comparable` I am receiving this as well from code above. It doesn't matter if it's a `Dict.get` or `Dict.member`...

Comment: You had also flipped the argument order of `dictExist`. I've fixed the code in the answer.

Comment: My bad, thanks for the great explanation and updates; as always, it works great! Also doing just the `Dict.member` inline without function works as expected as well, I just wanted a generic function to do this...

Comment: how would I return the value based on the key then? I tried something similar like `getDictValue : comparable -> Dict comparable v -> Int
getDictValue key dict =   
    case Dict.get key dict of        
        Just _ -> 12
        Nothing -> 0` Of course it always returns 12, I want it to return the actual value instead.

Comment: Instead of using `_` for the value inside `Just`, give it a name, e.g. `Just val -> val`.  However, in that case, you probably want to use `Maybe.withDefault` instead, e.g. `Dict.get key dict |> Maybe.withDefault 0`

Comment: @bdukes `Something is off with the 1st branch of this case expression:

111|         Just val -> val
                         ^^^
This val value is a:

    v

But the type annotation on getDictValue says it should be:

    Int` That is what I am getting now...

Comment: You should really ask this in a separate question so a proper explanation can be given. Or try going through a proper tutorial, since this is pretty basic stuff. But the problem is that the type signature says that you have a `Dict` of `v`s, which is a placeholder for essentially anything, but also says that the function should return an `Int`. So when you try to return a `v`, it points out the conflict. You can fix it by changing `Dict comparable v ` to `Dict comparable Int`

Comment: @glennsl correct, I just figured this out about 2 minutes ago TBH, thanks for the update!